# How can we get the pathname to a script within itself, when `source` it?

Tags: bash, scripting, source

I have a script to verify the positional parameters it receives

```
$ cat myscript
#! /bin/bash
echo $0
echo $1
echo $2
```

When I run it via different ways

```
$  ./myscript   
./myscript

$ bash ./myscript 
./myscript

$ source myscript
/bin/bash
```

Suppose I have to write another script which needs to get the pathname to the parent directory of the script:

```
#! /bin/bash

echo $(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")
```

and I have to run it by `source` it. Then it won't work, because `$0` is `/bin/bash`. I wonder how I can get the pathname to the parent directory of the script within itself, when `source` it? Thanks.

Comment: see $BASH_SOURCE . I could swear this is a duplicate question.

Comment: Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35006505/156458